# Oracle: Split column can improve query efficiency?

Tags: oracle

Suppose field `createtime`(yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss) belongs to table `transaction_tbl`.

Someone told me to split this field into two fields: `createdate`(yyyy-MM-dd) and `createtime`(HH:mm:ss), so query efficiency can speed up according to the time.

Does it make sense?

Ok,some more detail:

1. `createtime` datatype: `varchar2`;
2. search transaction records by the field `createtime`;
3. currently,no index on the field `createtime`.

Comment: Not really. What is the data type now, date or varchar2? If you need to search by time - ignoring the date part - for some reason then a virtual column or function-based index would make more sense. Depends what you are actually doing though. Please add more details to the question. If you have a query that you want to speed up include that, and its execution plan.

Comment: No it does not make sense. Do ***not*** store dates or timestamps as `varchar`. Never.

Comment: @a_horse_with_no_name  "15:33:24" is neither a date nor a timestamp

Comment: @miracle173: but data formatted as `yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss` is a timestamp. And that should **not** be stored as a `varchar`. Splitting up a (proper) timestamp doesn't really make sense either (especially as long as Oracle does not have a real DATE or TIME data type). And I can't picture any situation where storing a date and a time as `varchar` would speed up any query. A properly indexed `timestamp` will most probably be more efficient

Comment: The only situation where it might make sense to separate date and time (but both _not_ as `VARCHAR2`) is, if your distinct date values have comparable low cardinality and you could benefit from a bitmap index. See https://docs.oracle.com/cd/A97630_01/server.920/a96520/indexes.htm for more information about bitmap indexes.